# Getting GPS location in my Android Wearable in China

Tags: android, gps, wear-os

I am developing an Android app for a smartwatch that was bought and it's running in China.

My goal is to get the GPS location of the device and track its movement, but I cannot seem to find how to make it work.

Currently, I'm developing for API 21 and I'm using the following library of Google Play Services, as it is the one used by Wearables in China:     `com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.8.87`

The code that I am using is the following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_on_route);

    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS)
            .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL_MS);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)  // used for data layer API
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    startTravelTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (!hasGps()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "This hardware doesn't have GPS.");
    }
}

private boolean hasGps() {
    return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Log.i("Connected!!!", "WERE CONNECTED");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    System.out.println("onstop");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, OnRouteActivity.this);
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Successfully requested location updates");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG,
                                "Failed in requesting location updates, "
                                        + "status code: "
                                        + status.getStatusCode()
                                        + ", message: "
                                        + status.getStatusMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){

    // Display the latitude and longitude in the UI
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
    mTextView.setText("Latitude:  " + String.valueOf( location.getLatitude()) + "\nLongitude:  " + String.valueOf( location.getLongitude()));
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Latitude:  " + String.valueOf( location.getLatitude()) + "\nLongitude:  " + String.valueOf( location.getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For location to work on Chinese wearable devices you should use the [Fused Location Provider API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) and make sure to include the following line in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
}
```

In addition to the above you also need to add:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.0'
}
```

More details can be found in Google's guide [Creating Android Wear Apps for China](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating-app-china.html)

Comment: The problem is when I use that version of Google Play Services I get the following error: _Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10298000 but found 7571430_

Do you know any lower version that could work with my watch?

Comment: I'm using the emulator (part of the Canary 9 build for Android Studio 3.0) to test my apps. So far I haven't had any issues. I don't know if you can use a lower version, but based on the documentation it doesn't sound like it. Maybe your watch has to be considered too old, and not supported?

Comment: I thought about that possibility :( I will test my code with the emulator to see if it's working on there and if it is, the problem will be definitely the watch's version. Thank you!

Comment: do later versions of Play Services Location also work in China? the documents still point to 10.2.0